# I got first place in a competition where it's possible to tie. How would I distinguish that I was an untied first?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I would like to avoid using the phrase "untied first" unless that is actually the accepted way to say it.

Comment: I think most would assume that "first place" means an untied first unless the context has introduced it as a question. I have heard "undisputed first place" for emphasis instead of clarification.

Comment: What @jboneca said. If you came *first*, you beat *everyone* else. If there was a tie, you'd come ***joint** first*.

Comment: Agreed with the previous two comments -- if you 'came in first' you came in first without tying. If you tied with someone else, you "tied for first."

Comment: The competition is graded by score -- total amount of questions right over questions given. In this case, it is 30/30. However, it is reasonable to think that other people also got that score, but in this case that was not true. Is the assumption still that I was not tied for first?

Answer (score 4):

In sports news they call it having **sole possession of first place**.

Comment: This is what I would use and I hear it often.

Comment: This would be correct, but I'd only use it cases where you have reason to believe the reader could think you were tied for first - the default usage is for "first place" to imply sole and require a modifier ("tied for first place") if that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Unequivocal winner.
She was the unequivocal winner.
She won unequivocally.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any risk of confusion, you might say "I scored first overall" or "I scored the highest number of points in the competition."

And congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

If you really care, just say that you got **more points than anyone else**. End of story.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, first place is just called first place. If you'd shared the position, it'd be *joint first place*. So you don't normally need to explicitly state that you were the only person who earned first place. It's assumed.